# Writing UDF in Python for Pig

Tags: python, apache-pig, udf

I've struggled on this problem for several hours. Hope anyone can help me. The input is bag structure, such as `{([1,2]),([3,4])}`, and the goal is to output the sum of corresponding element of tuples in the bag, say `(4,6)`. Thanks a lot.

My code:

```
@outputSchema('aa:chararray')
def func(input):
    aa = map(sum,zip(*,input)) 
    aa = str(aa)
    return aa
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guess. The message:

```
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'
```

refers to the fragment:

```
  map(sum,zip(*,input))
```

and what it means is that you are trying to take the sum a unicode tuple, e.g. `[u'1', u'2']` rather than a tuple of int's, e.g. `[1,2]` as you think you are working with.

If that's the case, then you can wrap the zip inside a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do the conversion from unicode to int:

```
 [map(int, a) for a in zip(*,input)]
```

But you may have another error lurking. Judging by `@outputSchema('aa:chararray')` you want to return a list of string, not a single string; `str([1,2])` is `"[1,2]"` and I think you want `["1", "2"]`. If that's the case (and it might not so you should check), you could wrap that too in a list comprehension:

```
aa = [str(s) for s in aa]
```

Incorporating these two changes, your code becomes:

```
@outputSchema('aa:chararray')
def func(input):
    aa = map(sum,[map(int, a) for a in zip(*,input)])
    aa = [map(str, a) for a in aa]
    return aa
```

If from this, you can't solve the problem, it would be helpful to have more information. For example, does that type error point to a particular line in your code? If so, which line?

Perhaps you can show what the types of `input` or `*` are. For example change your function from:

```
 ...
 def func(input):
   aa = map(sum,zip(*,input)) 
 ...
```

to:

```
 def func(input):
   print(map(type, input))
   print(map(type, *))
   aa = map(sum,zip(*,input))
```